# ExcelPackage.Dispose() blocks input from serial port

Tags: c#, epplus

My application needs to open a Serial port and wait for data to be transmitted. After opening the serial port, I use EPPlus to read data from an excel sheet and store it in a list of dictionaries.

However, when I added the Read method, I stopped receiving data from the Serial port. After some testing, the serial port seems to break when .Dispose() is called on the ExcelPackage I use to read the excel sheet.

My Excel reading code is as follows:

```
public List<Dictionary<string, string>> Read(string fileName)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, string>> dictList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        FileInfo file = Utils.GetFileInfo(fileName, false);

        // using statement automatically calls Dispose() which closes the package.
        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
        {
            // Reads the first worksheet of the workbook
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
            int endColumn = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
            int endRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

            // Start loop from 2nd row to avoid headers
            for (int row = 2; row <= endRow; row++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                for (int column = 1; column <= endColumn; column++)
                {
                    // Add key value pair to dict for every column
                    // key = column header
                    // value = cell value to string

                    // key is set to "" if cell is empty
                    string key = worksheet.Cells[1, column].Value == null ? "" : worksheet.Cells[1, column].Value.ToString();
                    // value is set to "" if cell is empty
                    string value = worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value == null ? "" : worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value.ToString();

                    dictionary.Add(key, value);
                }
                dictList.Add(dictionary);
            }
        }
        return dictList;
    }
```

And my Serial Port is opened in a different class:

```
public BarcodeScanner()
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(SearchComPort());
            mySerialPort.Open();
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            isAvailable = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code seems to work if I use

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file)
```

And omit the .Dispose() call at the end, but from my understanding that would cause issues down the line since it makes the Excel worksheet unavailable to other processes.

Comment: Hmm, no, that would be the Butterfly Effect and C# does not suffer from that. As posted, the serial port is going to behave completely randomly. The code does not provide the essential configuration. Baudrate, Stopbits, Parity, Databits. And Handshake in particular, an easy way to get Read() to block.  Switching back-and-forth to a terminal emulator program is an easy way to get the defaults to change without noticing.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?
The barcode scanner gets a string from SearchComPort(), for example "COM4".
I checked the code used by SerialPort and Baudrate, Parity, etc have default values, such as 9600 for baudrate. Using these default value's has worked without issue thus far.

Answer (score 0):

What if you read all the data into a byte array using `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName)`, get that into a stream, then open the excel file using one of the (stream) overloads of EPPlus's ExcelPackage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and excuse me for taking a while to answer!
I tried this method, but it seems to exhibit the same problems. I have since modified my code to do `ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage` instead of `using ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage` and omitting the `Dispose()` call.
It seems like a bad practice, but I'm not aware of any other solution as of yet. Doing this, the application functions on my desktop, but doesn't function on my laptop.